# Apache Flink transform DataStream (source) to a List?

Tags: java, apache-flink

My question is how to transform from a `DataStream` to a `List`, for example in order to be able to iterate through it.

The code looks like :

```
package flinkoracle;

//imports
//....

public class FlinkOracle {

    final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FlinkOracle.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("Starting...");
        // get the execution environment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        TypeInformation[] fieldTypes = new TypeInformation[]{BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO};

        RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypes);
        //get the source from Oracle DB
        DataStream<?> source = env
                .createInput(JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
                        .setDrivername("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                        .setDBUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521")
                        .setUsername("user")
                        .setPassword("password")
                        .setQuery("select * from  table1")
                        .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
                        .finish());

        source.print().setParallelism(1);

        try {
            LOG.info("----------BEGIN----------");
            env.execute();
            LOG.info("----------END----------");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LOG.info("End...");
    }

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.
Br
Tamas

Comment: Hello Thomas and welcome to Stackoverflow, you should provide what you have already try. [more information here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: Hello Yanis,  I tried something like this:              source.flatMap(new Splitter()).keyBy(0).sum(1);  public static class Splitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String,String>>
{
@Override    
    public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<Tuple2<String, String>>out)throws Exception
    {
        for (String word: sentence.split(","))
        {
            LOG.info("FOR...");
            out.collect(new Tuple2<String,String>(word,""));
            
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want to accomplish when you iterate on DataStream? Most likely, better way would be to express that logic using DataStream APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Flink provides an iterator sink to collect DataStream results for testing and debugging purposes. It can be used as follows:

```
import org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.DataStreamUtils;

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> myResult = ...
Iterator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> myOutput = DataStreamUtils.collect(myResult)
```

You can copy an iterator to a new list like this:

```
while (iter.hasNext())
    list.add(iter.next());
```

Flink also provides a bunch of simple write*() methods on DataStream that are mainly intended for debugging purposes. The data flushing to the target system depends on the implementation of the OutputFormat. This means that not all elements sent to the OutputFormat are immediately shown up in the target system. Note: These write*()  methods do not participate in Flink’s checkpointing, and in failure cases, those records might be lost.

```
writeAsText() / TextOutputFormat
writeAsCsv(...) / CsvOutputFormat
print() / printToErr()
writeUsingOutputFormat() / FileOutputFormat
writeToSocket
```

Source: [link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/datastream_api.html#collection-data-sources).

You may need to add the following dependency to use DataStreamUtils:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-contrib</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Nizar, thanks for your help. I tried to import org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.DataStreamUtils; but I got the error message: package does not exist. I use apache flink 1.4.2. I have seen in the documentation that this is a existing package and thats why I don't understand it. Please help.

Comment: I believe the class was moved to package: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream. Link: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/022cd628cea67ce8eba1d56987301d20f192f480/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStreamUtils.java  Try: import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamUtils.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't help according NetBeans IDE DataStreamUtils is not in this package.

Comment: @Thomas Updated the answer with the required dependency in order to be able to use namespace:  org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.DataStreamUtils

Comment: Hi, it helped but now I have problem with 2 imports.  org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.* and org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.RowTypeInfo;   package does not exist error message. Of course I added the other dependencies as well as: <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
  <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I could solve it and now it is compilable. But the following doesn't work:                  DataStream<Tuple4<String, String, String, String>> myResult = source;

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions, [`DataStreamUtils::collect`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStreamUtils.html#collect-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream-) has been deprecated. Instead you can use [`DataStream::executeAndCollect`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#executeAndCollect-int-) which, if given a limit, will return a `List` of at most that size.

```java
var list = source.executeAndCollect(100);
```

If you do not know how many elements there are, or if you simply want to iterate through the results without loading them all into memory at once, then you can use the [no-arg version](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStream.html#executeAndCollect--) to get a [`CloseableIterator`](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/java/org/apache/flink/util/CloseableIterator.html)

```java
try (var iterator = source.executeAndCollect()) {
  // do something
}
```